# Combining process substitution with a here string

Tags: bash, process-substitution, herestring

I am trying to combine the results of a command and a here string like this:

```
cat <(echo first) <<< second
```

I am getting this output:

```
first
```

Instead of

```
first
second
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [man cat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html):

> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

But with file different then `-`, standard input is not read.

I guess you'll want:

```
cat <(echo first) - <<<second
```